# Return hourly and half hourly data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database that has numerous tables and I have joined two of the tables together and it is working fine but I now want to return the data that falls on half hour intervals! I have read numerous articles on this and I cant seem to get it to work. Below shows an example of my database

[image]

Below is the SQL that I have written to join the two tables

```
SELECT     
 Table2.SourceID, 
 Table2.Value, 
 Table1.Name, 
 Table2.TimestampUTC
 FROM         Table2 INNER JOIN
                  Source ON Table1.SourceID = Table1.ID 
 Where Table2.Value is not NULL
 ORDER BY Table2.TimestampUTC DESC
```

I have tried numerous examples so any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: So the data can only contain timestamps that are 0, 15, 30 and 45 minutes past the hour, seconds and milliseconds are always 0, and you want to *filter* this data (as opposed to, say, grouping together/aggregating it) so that you only have the rows with timestamps of 0 or 30 minutes past the hour?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I need to do! I Only want the data that falls within that dataset

Comment: your join condition looks wrong: `ON Table1.SourceID = Table1.ID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174420.aspx) function to extract the minutes from a `datetime` value:

```
SELECT     
 Table2.SourceID, 
 Table2.Value, 
 Table1.Name, 
 Table2.TimestampUTC
 FROM         Table2 INNER JOIN
                  Source ON Table1.SourceID = Table1.ID 
 Where Table2.Value is not NULL
 and DATEPART(minute,Table2.TimestampUTC) in (0,30)
 ORDER BY Table2.TimestampUTC DESC
```

(Usually, you'd be advised not to apply functions to columns so that indexes might be useful but, given the nature of this query, it's unlikely that a way can be found to write it that would be able to benefit from indexes anyway)

---

If you only want rows from today, then an additional filter can be applied:

```
SELECT     
 Table2.SourceID, 
 Table2.Value, 
 Table1.Name, 
 Table2.TimestampUTC
 FROM         Table2 INNER JOIN
                  Source ON Table1.SourceID = Table1.ID 
 Where Table2.Value is not NULL
 and DATEPART(minute,Table2.TimestampUTC) in (0,30)
 and Table2.TimestampUTC >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)
 and Table2.TimestampUTC < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),1)
 ORDER BY Table2.TimestampUTC DESC
```

Where `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0)` computes "today at the starting midnight" and `DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),1)` computes "tomorrow at the starting midnight" and these comparisons to `TimestampUTC` might be able to benefit from an index on that column now.

Comment: That worked perfectly but what if I wanted it to return data for every half hour on todays date? I don't want to write the date in by hand but I want it to be dynamic so if the date changes then it will be able to handle that without me having to change it manually?

Comment: @user3538102 - added as a second query.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do with use of the [`DatePart Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Add to your where clause:

```
AND DATEPART(minute, TIMESTAMP) in (0, 30)
```

To filter for a particular date add:

```
//Converting to varchar with sytle 101 strips off the time values, then we convert it back to a datateime for comparison
AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, 101)) = '1/1/2015'
```

To filter for Today add:

```
//Converting to varchar with sytle 101 strips off the time values, then we convert it back to a datateime for comparison
AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, 101)) = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but what if I wanted it to return data for every half hour on todays date? I don't want to write the date in by hand but I want it to be dynamic so if the date changes then it will be able to handle that without me having to change it manually?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data on half hour intervals, then you can use the `minute` component of the datetime field:

```
SELECT t2.SourceID, t2.Value, s.Name, t2.TimestampUTC
FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN
     Source s
     ON t2.SourceID = t2.ID 
WHERE t2.Value is not NULL AND
      datepart(minute, t2.TimestampUTC) in (0, 30)
ORDER BY t2.TimestampUTC DESC;
```

I also fixed your query so you don't have undefined table aliases, such as `table1`.

Comment: this also worked but could you read the comment I have written below the above two comments and give me some guidance on this?

Comment: Damien's answer seems to address your questions.  You should probably accept it.